# WCF PUT Service with multiple parameters

Tags: wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF PUT Service as:

```
http://dummyurl/EmployeeUpdate?id=99999&item={"var1":true,"var2":1,"var3":1}
```

Below is the service which is already available (should be a working WCF service)

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "EmployeeUpdate/{id}")]
string UpdateEmp(string id, Employee emp);


public string UpdateEmp(string id, Employee emp)
    {

        try
        {
    // process data 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
    // handle exception 
        }
        return IsSuccess;
    }
```

When I run the service, getting the error message as:
    The exception message is 'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I tried to figure out but unable to fix. Found that PUT method will only accept one parameter and the service also defined to receive only one parameter but function is defined with two parameters. I am not understanding how to pass my data as one parameter and how it is resolved in the function

Please provide some guidance on this

Answer (score 0):

Well, this exception can be resolved by 2 way:

1- you must use only one parameter this is due to the UriTemplate :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "EmployeeUpdate/{id}")]
string UpdateEmp(string id, Employee emp);
```

you must use it like this:

```
WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "EmployeeUpdate/{id}/{item}")]
string UpdateEmp(string id, Employee item);
```

I've added /{item} since in the uri you have item instead of emp.

2- You can also create a new object and put your parameter in it

```
public class ParamClass
{
    public string id;
    public Employee emp;
}
```

if you choose this solution you'll have to change your parameter for UpdateEmp accordingly to this change like :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "EmployeeUpdate/{emp}")]
string UpdateEmp(ParamClass emp);
```

also don't forget to change the "EmployeeUpdate" parameter and use in the other part of your archi.

Comment: Thank you. .  When I tried option 1 to see if it works, I got server error and not sure with this change other services are also not working so I have rolled back this change. Option 2, Really I should not change the interface as it is consumed by other apps as well. .    Strongly feel that the interface is right and I am not calling it with right way (using one parameter)

Comment: in the Uri `id=99999&item={"var1":true,"var2":1,"var3":1}` it's pretty clear that what is needed is two parameter : id and item